# openssl 0.9.8.j possible bug

Tags: openssl

I am working on ssl client using openssl library 0.9.8j in C.I need to connect to a server and to verify server's certificate.First I do test this way:

openssl s_client -connect 46.38.167.198:443 -CAfile /home/user/Desktop/sf_sharewin/tftp/verisign.pem

It works fine on version 0.9.8g on my Linux machine.But when I use version 0.9.8j on my uCLinux device the same test the result is "error 20 unable to get local issuer certificate".

I wrote some C code (under ucLinux and 0.9.8j version) and the function SSL_get_verify_result(ssl) return the same error 20.
I am sure that PEM file is the correct one and the path is the correct one.
Where could be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you use the right CA Certificate as CAFile ? I've downloaded the Issuer Certificate and everything works fine. And by the please update your openssl lib since 0.9.8j has known vulnerabilities. current version is 0.9.8x.

Comment: You're probably missing some certificates in the certificate chain.  OpenSSL 0.9.8h removed all built-in CA certs so probably 0.9.8g worked because the cert you needed in the chain was built in.

Comment: Now I see that the problem might be in the script shlib_wrap.sh because "make test" fails with error " word unexpected (expecting ")")
"

Comment: I still don't understand why opennssl can't recognize signed certificate.I tried this: